# ¿Porque me sale error 404?

Tags: php, laravel, error404, routes

No me deja crear un nuevo registro ,al parecer sera algun error de rutas,pero estan bien,genere mis rutas con un resource, antes me funcionaba pero de repente dejo de funcionar, subo screenshots:
Path: views/municipalidad/create.blade.php

Error:
[image: Error]

Ruta:
[image: rutas]
Btns :

```php
 Route::get("municipalidad/{periodo?}",[MuniRegistros::class,"index"])->name("municipalidad.index");
    Route::post("municipalidad/search}",[MuniRegistros::class,"search"])->name("municipalidad.search");

    Route::resource('municipalidad', MuniRegistros::class)->parameters(["municipalidad" => "registro"])->except(["index","destroy"]);
```

Controlador:

```php
  public function create()
    {
        return view("municipalidad.create");
    }
```

Por alguna razon funciona la ruta "municipalidad.create" cuando añado las dos rutas extras despues de la ruta resource,y me funciona,pero se me produce otro inconveniente,me envia al municipalidad.show,se supone que se hace antes de la rutas resource,es posible que se envia a esa rutas "municipalidad.show" por el orden de las rutas como tal,no especifique que sea enviado ahi

Comment: No nos castigues con código en imagen porfa :)

Comment: en las rutas no se ve municipaliadad registro pero no create

Comment: @Alfabravo Srry jaja, ahora lo edito.

Comment: @Bryro A que te refieres?

Comment: Cambia el código a texto por favor.

Comment: @Jorgesys Cambiado!

Comment: Que pasa si pones esta ruta `Route::get("municipalidad/{periodo?}",[MuniRegistros::class,"index"])->name("municipalidad.index")` después de las otras? O sea, primera la ruta resource, segunda la otra, y por último la que te menciono. No olvides limpiar la cache de rutas si no notas cambios

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Hola! , ya lo he  solucionado,cambien la url en vez de : Route::get("municipalidad/{periodo?}",[MuniRegistros::class,"index"])->name("municipalidad.index") lo cambie por : Route::get("municipalidad/registros/{periodo?}",[MuniRegistros::class,"index"])->name("municipalidad.index")

Comment: @Jorgesys Al parecer habia conflicto por el tema de que las urls eran similares,le puse otro nombre mas descriptivo : municipalidad/registros/{periodo?} y me funciono sin problemas!, se deberá a eso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya solucioné el problema,al parecer me indicaba esa problematica , por las urls similares entre las dos o tres rutas que se pueden apreciar en la imagen, cambie municipalidad/{periodo?} por municipalidad/registros/{periodo?} y me funciono!, si alguien conoce más a fondo este problema ,me gustaría saber la explicación a esta problematica que puede llegar a ser bastante común,saludos!

Comment: La ruta (get) `municipalidad/{periodo}` y `municipalidad/{registro}` son la misma. Y creo recordar que la última declarada en el fichero de rutas es la que se ejecuta. Así que la mejor solución es la que tu has adoptado. Cambiar el slug.